# How can I convince DateTime object (initialized with pytz timezone) to get me a timezone code recognized by pytz? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, timezone, python-3.5, pytz

```
import pytz
import datetime

timezone = pytz.timezone('Poland')
date = timezone.localize(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1))
pytz.timezone(date.tzname())
```

Unfortunately in Python 3.5.2, with  it crashes with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timezones.py", line 6, in <module>
    pytz.timezone(date.tzname())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 178, in timezone
    raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'CEST'
```

In one part of program timezone aware time object is created. In other part it is necessary to get timezone identifier back.

To avoid XY issues: I am calculating sunrise and sunset data using `skyfield` library. To do this I need to pass timezone as one of parameters.

From what I see at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html there is a `timezone` but for setting timezone, not getting it.

Comment: `Poland` is shorter and more readable than `Europe/Warsaw` so I will keep using it as long as it works.

Comment: According to the [list of timezone names in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) `Poland` is deprecated, replaced by `Europe/Warsaw`

Comment: The compiler doesn't care about the length and using the standard name ensures you won't have to check whether it still works, nor have to fix code you've forgotten about once it breaks. It also means you won't have to map timezone names that come from other libraries, files or programs, perhaps even your own

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using it in the config file, and it is not interfering in any way whatsoever with timezone names that come from other libraries, files or programs (in the config file it is transformed into a pytz timezone object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TZ database timezone name is stored as the `zone` attribute of the zone object returned by `pytz.timezone()`:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> timezone = pytz.timezone('Poland')
>>> date = timezone.localize(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1))
>>> date.tzinfo.zone
'Poland'
```

As you can see, the zone object itself is available as `date.tzinfo` after calling `localize()`, so you can just use that directly instead of passing the name back into `pytz.timezone()` if that's why you need it.